# Проблема с использованием скрипта на windows

Tags: python, скрипт, перебор

Не получается корректно запустить скрипт по проверке аккаунтов

git - https://github.com/behnambm/nordvpn-checker

выдаёт просто список аккаунтов с подписью none, при том что проверяет и заведомо рабочие

Answer (score 1):

Если вы вдруг не заметили, то на страничке автор четко дал понять, что

> NOTE : This script works only in linux.